# JQuery not executing functions, works in JSFiddle but not Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Here's a JSFiddle link with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ChristianIPS/nffkptky/2/

Clicking the button should trigger the function, but nothing happens. There are no errors in the console.

I define the jquery library with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.websitename.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery-1.11.3.min_.js"/>
```

What could be going on?

Comment: WordPress includes jQuery by default...I'm not sure why you're including it again, especially from the `uploads/` directory

Comment: @rnevius How should I use the default jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I have check your jquery path and found that there is `undersoce` `_` in the jquery file name : `/jquery-1.11.3.min_.js` so please check in upload folder/directory is jquery library file available with the same name or not?

Comment: The "www.websitename.com" part is meant to be an example url

Comment: have you check that there is file available in that directory?

Comment: Yes, and I've also tried using Google's:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: add `init()` after it declare

Comment: Do you mean like this? `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ipspeople.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery-1.11.3.min_.js">
jQuery(document).ready(init);
function init() {}`
If so, it doesn't work.